# How to make a selected checkbox change the price of my product

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

So in this mobile version of a landing page for my client, if you'll look (link below) at the three package options, you'll see that each has a Shipping Protection checkbox within it. I need this to be checked automatically as it is now, but when it is unchecked I need the total price directly underneath to drop by $4.99. So for example, the top package says "Only USD $149.94" right now, but when the Shipping Protection checkbox is unchecked, I need it to say "Only USD $144.95". I know this will involve javascript... if anyone could examine the code and tell me the best way, that'd be amazing! Thanks!

The link is: [HERE](http://entycemedia.com/landing/v4/m2/order2c.html)

Thanks again!

Comment: Try it for yourself and if you have any actual questions about actual code then come back.  And read the rules before your next question.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have any code to show, here is only some dummycode:

**Javascript:**

```
 var check = document.getElementById('check');
    check.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!check.checked) {
             var test = parseFloat(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
             document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = (test - 4.99).toFixed(2);
            }
        else {
            var test = parseFloat(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = (test + 4.99).toFixed(2); }
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">144.95</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" checked />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrg01xy4/2/)